# Nilpotent Lie algebra question

Tags: lie-algebras

Can someone please help me to prove the following statement:

In $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ we consider the Lie algebra generated by the vectors field:

$X_j=∂_{q_j},\hspace{1cm} Y_j=∂_{q_j}V(q)iτ_0,\;j=1,...,d$

where $V$ is a polynomial in  $R[x_1,..,x_d]$ of degree less or egal to $r$

then the lie algebra is nilpotent and its order is equal to the degree of $V$.

Comment: What is $i\tau_0$ ? Is $i^2=-1$ ?

Comment: yes $i^2=-1$ and $\tau_0\in\mathbb{R}$